# How do I get my class defined in my TD to take precedence over the general class defined for TDs?

Tags: html, css, class, html-table

I have the following HTML ...

```css
#searchResults td {
  padding: 1px;
  word-break: break-word;
 }
 
 .noBreaks {
  word-break: normal;
 }
```

```html
<td class="noBreaks" align="center">MYWORD</td>
```

HOwever it seems like my "noBreaks" class is getting canceled out by the "#searchResults td" class.  I would like the "noBreaks" class to take precendence (that is, have its rules respected instead of the other class).  How can I make that class be used instead of the "searchResults td"?

Comment: What does F12 tools say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `#searchResults .noBreaks`. An ID with a tag name in CSS is creating higher specificity than a class name alone. Here is some documentation on CSS specificity https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to an element in CSS, the more parent elements you name, the greater the specificity.  It's not necessarily that you have an id overriding a class; although that would be true if we were talking about *the same* element.

Given:

```
<div id="searchResults">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="noBreaks" align="center">MYWORD</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

This CSS will yield blue text:

```
#searchResults {
    color: red;
}

.noBreaks {
    color: blue;
}
```

This CSS will yield red text:

```
#searchResults td {
    color: red;
}

.noBreaks {
    color: blue;
}
```

So you can see here that the level of specificity is defined by how many parent selectors you use in your CSS rule, not necessarily their type (class vs. id).